# Command line args in F# fsx

Tags: f#

I run my `.fsx` file like

```
>fsi A.fsx
```

In this file I read csv with CsvProvider that has to have path to csv data.

```
type Data = CsvProvider<"my_data.txt", ";", Schema
```

I need to pass file name as command line argument and it is possible

```
 >fsi A.fsx my_data.txt
```

I can read it like

```
let originalPath = fsi.CommandLineArgs.ElementAt(1)
```

Problem is, that file name used in `CsvProvider` constructor needs to be constant and command line argument is not. How I can initialize CsvProvider from command line argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value inside the angle brackes `<"my_data.txt"...>` specifies an example format file and is checked at compile time, hence the need for it to be a constant string. Assuming your .fsx script merely wants to load a different CSV file of the same general format, you would use

```fsharp
let contents = Data.Load(originalPath)
```